# Pandas DataFrame to Json schema

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following dataframe and am unsure how I convert this to a useful Json output.

```
Name     Id    Qty   Value
thing1   123   10    12.5
thing2   456   20    15.4
thing3   789   40    84.2
```

I am currently using `to_json()`, but I'm a bit unsure of how to use this to result in the following json schema. I want

```
{"Name":"thing1"
 "Id":123,
 "Quantity":10, 
 "Value":12.5
 },
{"Name":"thing2"
 "Id":456,
 "Quantity":20, 
 "Value":15.4
 },
{"Name":"thing3"
 "Id":789,
 "Quantity":40, 
 "Value":84.2
 },
```

My solution that now works

```
out=df.reset_index().to_json(orient='record')
```

Comment: what happens to the rest of the data (ID 456 and 789)? You can also have a look at ``df.to_dict()`` options

Comment: Hi, sorry forget to add the others in. I'm by no means a json expert and just want it displayed in a readable fashion, so guessing can just do this?

Comment: You could try: `df.to_json(orient='records')`

Comment: That kind of worked, although it only included quantity and value. Is there a way to specify columns?

Comment: Maybe your `Name` and `id` are index ?   Try:  `df.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')`  ?

Comment: `df.to_dict("records")`

Comment: Thanks all! reset_index did the trick.

Comment: @RobRaymond  There's slight difference between the outputs of `to_dict()` and `to_json()`.  `to_dict()` gives single quotes outputs while `to_json()` gives double quotes, which seems better match OP's requirement.

Comment: fair enough - OPs question also excludes square brackets to represent list.  if there aren't needed I'd use a combination of `to_dict()` and `json.dumps()` as it is a string representation that's required not a **dict** repr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.to_json` with the `orient="records"` parameter:

```
import json
parsed = json.loads
result = df.to_json(orient="records")
parsed = json.loads(result)
json_out = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
print(json_out)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the orient parameter.

> ‘split’ : dict like {‘index’ -> [index], ‘columns’ -> [columns],
> ‘data’ -> [values]}
>
> ‘records’ : list like [{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]
>
> ‘index’ : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
>
> ‘columns’ : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
>
> ‘values’ : just the values array
>
> ‘table’ : dict like {‘schema’: {schema}, ‘data’: {data}}

```
import pandas as pd
import json
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Id', 'Qty', 'Value'])
df['Name'] = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3']
df['Id'] = [123, 456, 789]
df['Qty'] = [10, 20, 40]
df['Value'] = [12.5, 15.4, 84.2]
data = df.to_json(orient='records')
json.loads(data)
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': 'thing1', 'Id': 123, 'Qty': 10, 'Value': 12.5},
 {'Name': 'thing2', 'Id': 456, 'Qty': 20, 'Value': 15.4},
 {'Name': 'thing3', 'Id': 789, 'Qty': 40, 'Value': 84.2}]
```